# Displaying Navigation Menu on different pages in liferay?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, menu, web, liferay

I have started learning with Liferay 6.1

What I wish to achieve is: Displaying of Navigation Menus on several pages.

What I did is:

- Added Navigation portlet on a page and configured it to display all the links of pages (and also marking the current page link as bold)

What I researched is:

- I have read on several forums, that changing the `scopeable` tag of Navigation Portlet to true in `liferay-portlet.xml` file.

But the problem I am facing is:

- I could not find where liferay's Navigation portlet exist. Like I found its existence in `liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1/tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/navigation`, but then it doesn't contains any `liferay-portlet.xml` file in it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I have found some solutions, which makes a stable navigations menus to be displayed on the pages desired.

- First add a navigation menu to the page desired.
- Goto Dockbar-> Add -> Page. (Add your page's menu name).
- Goto Dockbar-> Manage-> Page
- Here you find an option of "Add portlets from page" -> Click -> Select the page where you have your navigation menu's placed.
- Select your page, and press "Copy" and then "Save".

Finally you will see your new page loaded with all the portlets found on your existing portlets, and the relevant menu link is selected too.

That's it.

Also you will see that all portlets are copied, so you can remove the one's you don't need. And also these lets you maintain the layout without modifying anything in your themes files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a PageTemplate to hold common portlets. Then when you create a page  you can pick the PageTemplate and your page will get all the portlets from that template

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for is in

```
ROOT/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml
```

Navigation portlet is portlet with name 71 (don't ask me why).

Anyway I dont understand what behaviour you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to display the same navigation on different portlet. I use to work with drupal, and there it was like creating menus and specifying the pages where I want it to appear. How can this be done with liferay? like display the same navigation portlet on different pages, rather than adding each of them individually on those pages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to make a theme? Maybe I'm being stupid here, but in themes there are the velocity templates for the layout of the whole portal (eg. footer, header and the space in the middle for portlets), and there is also the velocity code for the navigation. In practice it is something like:

```
<nav>
    #foreach($nav_item in $nav_items)
        ##do things with nav items for example get a child item:
        #if($nav_item.isSelected)
            #set($nav_childs = $nav_item.getChild()
        #end
    #end

    #foreach($child in $nav_childs.getChildren)
       ##do stuff with sub items
    #end
</nav>
```

Comment: It can't be done in theme. Consider it to be large portal rather than some website, modifying it in theme would make it a mandate for all the pages, and that is not what we require.

Comment: I think that one can't separate "core" portlets from the liferay portal framework. Maybe you could use the liferay-taglibs (http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/UI+Taglib#section-UI+Taglib-breadcrumb)?

Comment: You probably can get hold of com.liferay.portal.theme.NavItem service class somehow. I'm also learning liferay currently..